# How to duplicate a directory structure of one Windows machine to another one?

Tags: windows, powershell

And the following are the extra requirements.

1. Duplicate all the attributes, for example, the encryption and compression, as well.
2. Security settings
3. (Optionally copy Sharing)

Comment: dfs-r OR robocopy.exe/compact.exe/cipher.exe script OR powershell script?

Comment: These utilities don't copy attributes and permissions?

Comment: Is cloning the underlying disk an option?

Comment: @PervonZweigbergk No, the machines are at different location. Right now I'm just copy all the data structure. I may use rsync to copy the content.

Comment: Robocopy can copy attributes and security. - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty Does robocopy compress the traffic over the network?

Comment: Why not write the whole scenario complete with relevant details and all requirements into the question, you won't have to keep expanding it and we can help you with better answers and suggestions from the get go.

Answer (score 1):

As @joeqwerty pointed out, you can use `Robocopy`

```
robocopy [source] [destination] /COPYALL /DCOPY:T /MIR
```

`/COPYALL` will give you all your attributes.

`/MIR` will give you your directory structure.

Comment: The command got error of `ERROR : Invalid Parameter #4 : "/DCOPY:T"`.

Comment: `/xf *` is still needed to avoid to copy files.